# Talend Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, talend

I have a csv file from which I had inserted data into a **tPostgresSQLOutput** in Talend. Now I have made changes in the csv file and need to update the database as well in Talend. Any suggestions on how to use the action on data: update feature or any other method to update my data ?

Comment: Depends on use case... Update could be enough but expensive. Why not just try it out? If anything goes wrong, you can use the old version and the new version of your files and recreate the table.

Comment: The job runs without error however nothing is getting updated in my database. How exactly does the update feature work ?

Comment: Do you have a primary key so that the database can actually find data? If the database is not able to match records, it won't update them. Maybe try to switch to "Update or Insert" and have a look if the records get inserted actually.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the component called action on data, choose update. See [help.talend](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/7.83+tPostgresqlOutput)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have defined a key in your mapping (tMap component). Then edit the tMap componnent according to your new csv file changes. Then use insert or update action in  tPostgresSQLOutput. Then it will apply changes to updated records and will insert new records too. It will not update data if you do not have any key in your mapping